# Issue with installing GSLL with Quicklisp on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lisp, common-lisp, gsl, quicklisp

I am experiencing some trouble installing the Gnu Scientific Library for Lisp (GSLL) with Quicklisp. I am a noob in Common Lisp, but from what I've read I see a big potential in this language as a math Phd student for abstracting concepts. So, I haven't got deep in the details of the computer science side yet since my first objective is to solve my math problem.

I installed Quicklisp by following the instructions on [Quicklisp.org](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/#installation). When I load the library "vecto" as in the instructions, it works. But when I try to load GSLL, here is what I get. I hope to fully solve this problem with your help. Thank you.

```
(ql:quickload "gsll")

*** - Error while trying to load definition for system gsll from pathname
      /home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/gsll-20130312-git/gsll.asd:
      READ de #<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER

      #P"/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.0/libffi/built-in-types.lisp"
      @36> : #<PACKAGE CFFI> ne comprend pas de symbole externe de nom
      "*BUILT-IN-FLOAT-TYPES*".
Rentrées possibles:
RETRY          :R1      Retry compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-libffi" "libffi" "built-in-types">.
ACCEPT         :R2      Continue, treating compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-libffi" "libffi" "built-in-types"> as having been successful.
SKIP           :R3      skip (EVAL-WHEN # #)
RETRY          :R4      retry (EVAL-WHEN # #)
STOP           :R5      stop loading file /home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/gsll-20130312-git/gsll.asd
REINITIALIZE-SOURCE-REGISTRY-AND-RETRY :R6 Retry finding system gsll after reinitializing the source-registry.
ABORT          :R7      Give up on "gsll"
ABORT          :R8      Abort main loop
Break 1 CFFI[15]>
```

(edit)

Thank you, Nick Levine, with your help I updated the distribution of Quicklisp with the CLISP interpreter. It worked, I just got a warning. Then I tried to load GSLL and here is what I got :

```
[3]> (ql:quickload "gsll")
; cc -m64 -I/usr/share/common-lisp/source/cl-cffi/ -fPIC -o /home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix /home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:110:47: attention : format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:115:35: attention : format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:120:35: attention : format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:125:35: attention : format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:130:35: attention : format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:144:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:146:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:158:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:160:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:172:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:174:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:186:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:188:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:200:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:202:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:214:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:216:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:228:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:230:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:242:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:244:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:256:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:258:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:270:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:272:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:284:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:286:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:298:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:300:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:312:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:314:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:326:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:328:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:340:5: attention : format ‘%lli’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
/home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.c:342:5: attention : format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
; /home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix /home/monsieur/.cache/common-lisp/clisp-2.49-unix-x64/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/libffi-unix.grovel-tmp.lisp

*** - Error while trying to load definition for system gsll from pathname
      /home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/gsll-20130615-git/gsll.asd:
      READ de #<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER

      #P"/home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.2/libffi/built-in-types.lisp"
      @36> : #<PACKAGE CFFI> ne comprend pas de symbole externe de nom
      "*BUILT-IN-FLOAT-TYPES*".
Rentrées possibles:
RETRY          :R1      Retry compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-libffi" "libffi" "built-in-types">.
ACCEPT         :R2      Continue, treating compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-libffi" "libffi" "built-in-types"> as having been successful.
SKIP           :R3      skip (EVAL-WHEN # #)
RETRY          :R4      retry (EVAL-WHEN # #)
STOP           :R5      stop loading file /home/monsieur/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/gsll-20130615-git/gsll.asd
REINITIALIZE-SOURCE-REGISTRY-AND-RETRY :R6 Retry finding system gsll after reinitializing the source-registry.
ABORT          :R7      Give up on "gsll"
ABORT          :R8      Abort main loop
Break 1 CFFI[4]>
```

Comment: I didn't succeed in reproducing your error, as I don't have access to Ubuntu (or libffi, for that matter).

It always helps if you state explicitly which lisp (implementation & version you're using). Was this CLISP?

Also -- and this may be the helpful bit -- I see that you are using an out of date quicklisp distribution. You should run (ql:update-all-dists) and then start from scratch.

Any joy?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is likely: don't use CLISP. It is too much of a headache and time sink to workaround the bugs. SBCL works well, and CCL should work well too, both are excellent implementations of Common Lisp and available for Ubuntu 64 bit. If you still have trouble then please post another question.

From the [GSLL](http://common-lisp.net/project/gsll/) flysheet:

> Most users will not need to worry about their implementation and operating system, as all these are supported if the needed libraries are installed (see below). The use of CLISP, however, is not recommended.